# Add anotation to a serie if value is > 0

Tags: google-visualization

How to add annotation to serie C if value is > 0?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/hRpDp/2/)

What configuration with...

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

...is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a calculated annotation column via the chart's `view` parameter:

```
view: {
    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, {
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 3) > 0) ? 'Yes' : null;
        }
    }]
}
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/hRpDp/3/

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to show the value instead of "Yes"?